# Data Repository instance Null - NullReferenceException? Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Everything I've seen online, I'm supposed to instantiate an instance of my repo, which I believe I have done yet I'm still getting a null reference exception.

Here's the class which implements the `IArticleRepository` interface.

```
public class ArticleRepository : IArticleRepository
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext dbContext;
        public ArticleRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
        {
            this.dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        public void DeleteArticle(int articleId)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public async Task<Article> GetArticleAsync(int articleId)
        {
            Article article = await dbContext.Articles.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == articleId);
            return article;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Article>> GetArticles()
        {
            var articles = await dbContext.Articles.ToListAsync();
            return articles;
        }

        public void InsertArticle(Article article)
        {
            dbContext.Articles.Add(article);
        }

        public async void Save()
        {
            await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public void UpdateArticle(Article article)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

In my controller, I have:

```
private readonly ArticleRepository _ArticleRepo;

public ArticleController(){}

public ArticleController(ArticleRepository _ArticleRepo)
{
    this._ArticleRepo = _ArticleRepo;
}
```

So I'm instantiating an instance of the ArticleRepo(hopefully I did this correct).

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult New (Article article)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

            Article newArticle = new Article
            {
                Title = article.Title,
                Content = article.Content,
                AuthorId = userId,
                CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
                LastUpdated = DateTime.Now
            };

            _ArticleRepo.InsertArticle(newArticle);
            _ArticleRepo.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("Details", "Article", new { id = article.Id });
        }
    } catch (DataException)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists contact your system administrator.");
    }

   return View(article);
}
```

Getting the error when I hit `_ArticleRepo.InsertArticle(newArticle);`

Comment: You are injecting the dependency, but where are you mapping your types?  You have to show us your IOC config

Comment: I don't know. I'm trying to kind of follow the MSDN tutorial and doing a crap job of it. (but aiming to incorporate async methods). I didn't see anything in here about a config change  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application#implement-a-generic-repository-and-a-unit-of-work-class

Comment: Take a step back and look at your code, you take a `ArticleRepository` argument in your constructor, but where do you actually instantiate an `ArticleRepository`.  You havent shown that here, and if you dont have an _instance_ of that class you certainly cannot use a method of it (or else you get a `NullReferenceException`).  Also, you already have an abstraction for your repo (`IArticleRepository`), you should use _that_ as your constructor argument and reference.  This is the whole point of dependency injection

Comment: you're right. I added this private readonly ArticleRepository _ArticleRepo = new ArticleRepository(); and it worked.

Comment: Dont do that, that is the exact opposite of what you should be doing.  Your constructor should be `public ArticleController(IArticleRepository _ArticleRepo)` (note that it takes the _interface_ not the actual class).  Then you need to use an IOC container to _map_ the interface `IArticleRepository` to the concrete `ArticleRepository`.  You should never manually instantiate dependencies like this, always code off of abstractions

Comment: then if I don't generate an instance of the ArticleRepo there, where should I instantiate it?

Comment: okay. I'll look into that IOC thing because I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: You need to learn about Dependency Injection, this is a concept of programming and one of the SOLID principles.  A tool/library that helps you manage these "mappings" is called an IOC container (IOC = inversion of control).  There are a ton of IOC libraries (Ninject, SimpleInjector, the .NET Core one you can even import as a nuget package).

Comment: Yeah. I see it in one of the later courses in the C# Pluralsight path I'm doing. Not there yet. Just got to async programming in the advanced path...long road still to go. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the default constructor from your controller:

```
public ArticleController(){}
```

and this will outline the issue.  The example you are following is using Dependency Injection which is a very good pattern to be learning. Unfortunately, by default, MVC is expecting controllers **not** to have dependencies, though they have provided hooks to accommodate alternative controller factories. Most IoC containers (Inversion of Control, which goes hand-in-hand with Dependency Injection) support MVC controller injection.

Have a look into the Autofac IoC container as it is quite a good take on the pattern and is easy to configure/use, plus it has pretty good documentation.

https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/mvc.html

Alternatively you can read up on Unity, Ninject, Castle Windsor, or a number of others, but these 4 are arguably the most common ones you will find in the wild.